# CultureInfo and Double.parse and double.toString not worked correctly

Tags: c#, .net, double, cultureinfo, .net-4.6.2

How can I force c# application to use . for decimal separator and ignore culture settings in server. I have this problem with double.ToString and double.parse
I should change setting in application level because of large scale of application.

exception occurse in case like double.parse("1/25") and 1.25 ToString

I have Try This code

```
string CultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(CultureName);
        if (ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator != ".")
        {
            // Forcing use of decimal separator for numerical values
            ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        }
```

in app_start begin request and method that change culture but can't solve problem

The application was working correctly in .net 3.5 but after upgrade to .net 4.6.2 this problems happened on server 2012 and windows 10.

Comment: `double result = double.Parse("1.234", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Thank  @Dmitry Bychenko But I cant change every double.parse because it have been used 7000 time and also double.ToString raise unmatch data exception in our application. I should fixed in application level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined a method and use it in every where in application that changes cultureinfo

```
public static void CorrectNumberFormat()
    {
        var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
        if (culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator != ".")
        {
            culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
            culture.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalSeparator = ".";
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The direct way is to *specify* the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
 string source = "1.234";

 double result = double.Parse(source, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The by-way is to *assign* `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the current culture

```
var saved = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

try {
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

  ...

  double result = double.Parse(source);

  ... 
}
finally {
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = saved;
}
```

Finally, you may want to *modify* the existing current culture (kind of fixing "at application level"):

```
CultureInfo modified = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

modified.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

// Business as usual except the decimal separator which is now dot '.' 
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = modified;

...

double result = double.Parse(source);
```